# Hibernate Pool exhaustion too soon

Tags: mysql, hibernate, transactions, connection-pooling, dropwizard

I am working on a dropwizard application with the following configuration

```
database:
  driverClass: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
  user: "root"
  password: "mypassword"
  url: "jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/?autoReconnect=true"
  properties:
    charSet: "UTF-8"
    hibernate.dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"
    hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto: "create"
    hibernate.show_sql: true
  maxWaitForConnection: "1s"
  validationQuery: "/* MyApplication Health Check */ SELECT 1"
  minSize: 8
  maxSize: 32
  checkConnectionWhileIdle: true
  checkConnectionOnReturn: true
  checkConnectionOnBorrow: true
```

I have the following transaction

```
@Transactional
    public void createOrSave(Service service) {
        Service existingJar = getById(service.id);

        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            if (existing != null) {
                session.merge(service);
            } else {
                session.save(service);
            }
            tx.commit();

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            tx.rollback();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }

    }
```

And other such transactions that are of the same nature. The Pool gets exhausted very soon and the server starts returning a 500. My guess is that clients send requests too frequently , opening many connections before they return to the pool and hence I have no connections left in the pool.

I dont have control over the frequency of client connections. Is there any more configuration required to take care of this situation?

Comment: try to use flexypool and set your parameters while testing #AskHibernateVlad

Comment: Do you have an example? I only find the maven plugin when I search for it

Comment: check https://github.com/vladmihalcea/flexy-pool

Comment: should I be looking at codehale-metrics or c3p0?

Comment: Do you need the @Transactional annotation and to manually handle the transaction within the method? I would have thought only one of those is needed